# Class variable not accessible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure why but my class's variable is not accessible.
This is the class:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public string discription;
    public Sprite icon;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int level;
    public int damage;
}
```

and I'm creating new weapon from the class, but it should have access to `level`.

```cs
public class ItemDataBase : MonoSingleton<ItemDataBase>
{
    Weapon sword = new Weapon();
    sword.level = 1;//Error
}
```

[image]

Comment: @ThomasWeller It's a member regardless. That would make it a property rather than a field (which it should be, generally you shouldn't have public fields unless they're `const`). Anyway, you're trying to access it on the class-level. You can't access properties outside of a constructor or [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer). Read up on [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes).

Comment: Also I would recommend following the [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) (trust me, you and whoever else reads your code will thank me later).

Comment: * To clarify on my previous comment, you can't access properties *on the class level* with exception of constructor parameters or within an object initializer. You need to put those last couple lines into a constructor or method body in order to do that.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code in the question. I'd suggest you probably have two definitions of `Weapon`.

Answer (score 1):

It's error because you can create object inside Class but inorder to make changes in that object you need to put it inside a function you can't directly alter an object inside class.

You could make a constructor to initialize value on instantiation.

Example:

```
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public string discription;
    public Sprite icon;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int level;
    public int damage;

    public Weapon(int level)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }
}

public class ItemDataBase : MonoSingleton<ItemDataBase>
{
    Weapon sword = new Weapon(1); // this is same as sword.level = 1
}
```

Hope this helps.